# adViewWillDismissScreen in GADBannerViewDelegate is not called

Tags: ios, admob

I created `GADBannerView` and register the view controller as `GADBannerViewDelegate`. 
However I cannot make these two methods (`adViewWillDismissScreen` and `adViewDidDismissScreen`) call. Only `adViewWillPresentScreen` is called

I've followed the url http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/05/google-mobile-ads-sdk-note-on-ad-click.html
on both Simulator and iOS device. The two methods still not get called.
The below is my code.

```
self.mBannerView1        = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:CGPointMake(0, 100)];

self.mBannerView1.adUnitID              = kMyAdUnitID;
self.mBannerView1.rootViewController    = self;
self.mBannerView1.delegate              = self;

[self.mBannerView1 loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:self.mBannerView1];
```

Comment: Add your `GADBannerViewDelegate` methods to your question. Are you setting your `GADBannerView.delegate = nil` anywhere?

Comment: @DanielStorm , Thank you for your answer. I didn't set delegate to nil in the code.

Comment: Add the rest of your code.